# grails/ivy proxy exclusions?

Tags: grails, groovy, maven, ivy, nexus

I need to connect to a nexus repo of mine, but I'd also like the ability to grab files from the the central maven repository. If I use `grails add-proxy`, there's no way to set an exclusion list.

I'm behind a corporate proxy, and the nexus repo is within the proxy.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Nexus create a repository group includes the central repository. In that way Nexus is a "one stop shop" for all your dependencies.

More efficient and protects you against an internet outage. (Nexus will cache the central jars)